# Why does the text disappear from the text field after clicking Done in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I have a text field where the user enters text. But I ran into a problem when I enter text and press the Done button - the text disappears from the text field as if it never existed. But when the field is active and I enter characters, everything is visible. Why does the text disappear from the text field after clicking the Done button?

```
class CommentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(String) onChanged;
  final String? textForm;
  final bool isHelpPage;

  CommentWidget({Key? key, required this.onChanged, required this.textForm, required this.isHelpPage})
      : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  String value = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    controller.text = textForm ?? '';

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        isHelpPage
        ? const SizedBox()
        : const ResizedText(
          'Comments',
          textStyle: constants.Styles.smallTextStyleWhite,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: UiSize.getHeight(15, size),
        ),
        Container(
          height: UiSize.getHeight(isHelpPage ? 290 : 150, size),
          width: UiSize.getWidth(360, size),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            border: Border.all(
              color: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
              width: 0.5,
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: UiSize.getHeight(16, size),
              left: UiSize.getWidth(18, size),
              right: UiSize.getWidth(18, size),
              bottom: UiSize.getHeight(16, size),
            ),
            child: TextField(
              maxLines: isHelpPage ? 10 :4,
              maxLength: isHelpPage ? 1500 : 450,
              controller: controller,
              style: constants.Styles.smallerBookTextStyleWhiteOpacity,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              onChanged: (text) {
                onChanged(text);
                value = text;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                helperStyle: constants.Styles.smallerBookTextStyleWhiteOpacity,
                hintStyle: constants.Styles.smallerBookTextStyleWhiteOpacity,
                hintText: 'Here you can describe the problem in more detail',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you add onChanged? explain in details

Comment: Added all the code to the question

Comment: onChanged I use to write the value from the field and pass it to the previous screen from where I write this value to the database

Comment: Why did you add a controller? It seems unnecessary

Comment: I added parent widget code

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are rebuilding the textfield in the parent widget by maybe calling setState(...).

`controller.text = textForm ?? '';` then wipes your text because you are resetting the text every time you are building the widget.

Solution: Make the widget a StatefulWidget and let it cache the value of the TextField.

This could look something like this

```
class TextfieldWithCache extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextfieldWithCache(this.initialValue, this.onUpdate);
  
  final String initialValue;
  final Function(String) onUpdate;

  @override
  State<TextfieldWithCache> createState() => TextfieldWithCacheState();
}

class TextfieldWithCacheState extends State<TextfieldWithCache> {
  
  // if not used in this widget, the value can be deleted as well
  String _cachedValue;
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      initialValue: widget.initialValue,
      onChanged: (String value) {
        widget.onUpdate(value);
        _cachedValue = value;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Note: If you don't use the cached value in the TextfieldWithCache then you can remove it as well.

The core lies in using a StatefulWidget and getting rid of all helper methods involved in widget creation.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do this?

Comment: I added parent widget code

Comment: I can do this in the evening, not at home at the moment. Another smell i pot is the helper  method to create a widget. This causes unwanted rebuilds as well as Flutter is unable to cache the widgets

Comment: Well, if you can in the evening, then tell me with an example how to do it

Comment: I would like to remind you, if possible, show how to cache the value

Comment: and if I need to get the value from the text field on the ReportBody screen, then do I need to cache the value there?

Comment: and I can get the value from the textformfield on the ReportBody screen so that I can then transfer this value to the server?

Comment: You can pass a onUpdate(..) callback to the widget just like in your solution. The whole issue just comes from the improper usage of StatelessWidget which leads to rebuilding - apart from that your solution looks fine-ish

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the ReportBody to `Statefull Widget` and declare the text editing controller as and intialize it in the initState(),

```dart
late final TextEditingController controller;

@override
  void initState() {
    controller = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Then pass this controller to `CommentWidget` as a named parameter and use this controller to TextFormField.

Hope it works.

Comment: and I can get the value from the textformfield on the ReportBody screen so that I can then transfer this value to the server?

Comment: Yes, You can get all TextEditingController parameters in ReportBody screen. Have you find any answer?

Comment: I will try options to see what works